# how to write a .jpg file into a new file?

Tags: image, file, image-processing

I changed the extension of a .jpg file into .txt file, copied all the data, pasted it into another .txt file and changed the extension of this file to .jpg. But the image doesn't open. Why?

Comment: Binary files (jpg) and text-files are encoded differently. It depends on your editor what happens when you copy paste text, but in most cases this won't work. I did not read it, but [this might be a start](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Thank you @sascha

Comment: when you copy text certain codes are ommited,changed or processed like `ASCII<32`  so the copied content is not the same as original data. Some text editors even change the end line code and also Tab so if you got `0x10,0x13` or `0x09` in your data you're in trouble.  Not to forget about escape printer control codes ... Open both origina and new file in hex editor and see the differences ...